# Howto set Google Chrome Bookmarks with parameters?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Is there a way to set parameters in google chrome bookmarks? I have been using this in Mozilla Firefox for years.

example: A bookmark with URL www.url.de/vserver=%ID. In firefox I typed in to the adress-bar vserver:343 and firefox translated it into the right url: url.de/vserver=343

This would be really timesaving for some workflows.

Comment: BTW in Firefox that feature is called smart keywords and it doesn't work exactly like that. You have to explicitly set the "Keyword" field in the bookmark in order to work, e.g. "vserver" like the example, and then type "vserver 343" to make it work (the argument is separated by a space, not the `:` symbol). Read more about how to use it at https://kb.iu.edu/d/arjb

Answer (score 21):

`chrome://settings/searchEngines` sorry - because it's no bookmarks, it's called omnisearch in Google Chrome.

1. Go to `chrome://settings/searchEngines`
2. On the bottom, type your search tag and URL where parameter = `%s`
3. Type the tag in the address bar > Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> > Type in your parameter (for example, `3434`).
4. Chrome opens the right URL with the parameter typed in.

Comment: Interestingly, chromium actually seems to be creating these automatically from the pages you visit, using the whole url as keyword (which you can obviously still change)

Answer (score 7):

Go to the Chrome >> bookmarks >> bookmarks manager >> add new
Add Text

In url, type :

```
javascript:void(location.href='URL'+window.prompt("Text to be displayed",""));
```

Comment: Awesome. Awesome. Awesome.

Comment: doesn't seem to work any more (Chrome v89.0.4389.114)

Comment: @JohnPick maybe you tried it in a new tab. It works by using the trick I give [here](https://superuser.com/a/1648565/665721)

Answer (score 3):

I find [Rakesh's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1284394/665721) quite interesting but sadly doesn't work when used in a new tab.

One solutions thought is to use a trick seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56794455/1833364) :

```js
data:text/html,<script>window.location.href='url' + window.prompt("Text to be displayed","");</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in new versions of Chrome. (the "new tab" part)